# Bootstrap mark-up problems

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

**What I want:**

1: 
 What I want is that the `echo '<span class="badge bg-red">Denied</span>';` is directly under the `echo '<b><a href="https://####/reactie"> '</b></a>';` and that the `img` is the full height.

2: The second thing that I want is that there is a small line under the

`echo '<b><a href="https://####/reactie"> '</b></a>'; 
echo '<a> - ' . $topic['voornaam'] . '</a>';`

[How it looks like now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiFv3.png)

The code:

```
   <div class="box box-info">
    <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h3 class="box-title"><b>Topics</b></h3>
    </div><!-- /.box-header -->          

<div class="box-body">
     echo '<div id="topic">';
     echo '<img style="height:100%;"class="img-circle" src="###.'/'.###'" />'; 
       echo '<i class="fa fa-fw fa-user img-circle"></i>';
       echo '<b><a href="https://####/reactie"> '.$####'</b></a>'; 
       echo '<a> - ' . ####. " " . #### . '</a>';
       echo '<span style="float:right;"class="fa-stack"><span class="fa fa-comment-o fa-stack-2x"></span><strong class="fa-stack-1x" style="font-size:10px;">999</strong></span>';
       echo '<span class="badge bg-red">Denied</span>';
       echo '</div>';
    }
  ?>
    </div><!-- /.box-body -->
    <div class="box-footer text-center">
    </div><!-- /.box-footer -->
    </div><!-- /.box -->
```

The custom css:

```
#topic a {
    color: black;
    margin-left: 1%;
}

#topic {
    padding: 10px;
}

#topic i{
    font-size: 2.3em;
    width: 33px;
}
```

Comment: I don't really see much Bootstrap being used here. It looks like mostly custom CSS. Can you provide the rendered HTML instead of the PHP, and clarify it into a single question?

Comment: Updated the question and deleted as much PHP as possible, the question is still the same I need help with the mark-up. @ZimSystem

Comment: Is it better now? @ZimSystem and can you help me?